# Pagination jTable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-jtable

How to use paging in jTable use PHP?
I have code below in employeeTable.php

```
    <script src="jtable.2.4.0/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    //Get record count
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM employee;");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $recordCount = $row['RecordCount'];

    //Get records from database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY '" . $_REQUEST["jtSorting"] . "' LIMIT '" . $_REQUEST["jtStartIndex"] . "','" . $_REQUEST["jtPageSize"] . "';");

    //Add all records to an array
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

Then I realize the problem is in here

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY '" . $_REQUEST["jtSorting"] . "' LIMIT '" . $_REQUEST["jtStartIndex"] . "','" . $_REQUEST["jtPageSize"] . "';");
```

if I change $_REQUEST["jtSorting"] = rowname, $_REQUEST["jtStartIndex"] = number, $_REQUEST["jtPageSize"] = number, it works. 
But if I don't change it, it shows 'An Error Occured While Communicating to the server'.

here is the code in jquery.jtable.min.js, when there are line about jtSorting, jtStartIndex, jtPageSize

```
/* Adds jtSorting parameter to a URL as query string.
    *************************************************************************/
    _addSortingInfoToUrl: function (url) {
        if (!this.options.sorting || this._lastSorting.length == 0) {
            return url;
        }

        var sorting = [];
        $.each(this._lastSorting, function (idx, value) {
            sorting.push(value.fieldName + ' ' + value.sortOrder);
        });

        return (url + (url.indexOf('?') < 0 ? '?' : '&') + 'jtSorting=' + sorting.join(","));
    },

    /* Overrides _createJtParamsForLoading method to add sorging parameters to jtParams object.
    *************************************************************************/
    _createJtParamsForLoading: function () {
        var jtParams = base._createJtParamsForLoading.apply(this, arguments);

        if (this.options.sorting && this._lastSorting.length) {
            var sorting = [];
            $.each(this._lastSorting, function (idx, value) {
                sorting.push(value.fieldName + ' ' + value.sortOrder);
            });

            jtParams.jtSorting = sorting.join(",");
        }

        return jtParams;
    }

});
})(jQuery);
```

Can anybody please help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through this once.
[Listaction jtable for Pagination and sorting table](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/Actions#act-listAction)

It would require jQuery.Deferred to return data.

Handle it as

```
listAction: function (postData, jtParams) {
    return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Employee_Controller/EmployeeList_method?jtStartIndex=' + jtParams.jtStartIndex + '&jtPageSize=' + jtParams.jtPageSize + '&jtSorting=' + jtParams.jtSorting,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                $dfd.resolve(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                $dfd.reject();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Manually post values for it. I hope this maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the options will be received in $_GET object

like:

```
$jtStartIndex=$_GET['jtStartIndex'];
$jtPageSize=$_GET['jtPageSize'];
$jtSorting=$_GET['jtSorting'];
```

example:

```
$query="select * FROM products ORDER BY $jtSorting LIMIT $jtStartIndex, $jtPageSize;";
```

and in jtable settings:

```
paging: true, //Enable paging
pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
sorting: true, //Enable sorting
defaultSorting: 'name ASC' ,
            actions: {
                listAction: 'data/products.php'//Set default sorting
            },
...
```